# %t in Java folder structure

Tags: java, relative-path

I was reading a tutorial on Java logging and came across this line

```
Handler fh = new FileHandler("%t/wombat.log");
```

What is the `%t` supposed to represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'%t' is the system temporary directory.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html

Comment: I see - does that mean that this feature is local to FileHandler? Or is `%t` something you can use across the board?

Comment: I am inclined to think that this is particular to `FileHandler`, I have not come across %t being used for temp dir anywhere else.